# Crystal Report Multiple data sources - Table Not Found

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports version 13.0 in Visual Studio 2010.
Using the Command feature, all the fields needed are selected.
One of the fields is from a separate database on the same server.

```
SELECT r.ID, r.Revision, 
u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS UpdateBy, r.UpdateDate, 
s.Description AS Status, r.StatusID, r.Comments,    
c.Notes 
FROM Repel r 
INNER JOIN Status s ON r.StatusID = s.id 
INNER JOIN Conditions c ON c.SOCID = r.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Admin].[dbo].[Users] u ON u.ID = r.UpdateBy 
WHERE r.ID = {?item}
```

Using the database expert, both databases are connected but the command itself is on the main datasource.
The datasource with the tables Repel, Status, and Conditions.
It can NOT find the table Users.
The path is fully qualified so how can I get the report to see this table?
I know I could create a view in sql server itself and connect to that but there is a change that needs to be made to 30+ reports.

Thanks!!

**EDIT**
I tried to create a view in the main database only to use one datasource.
Then changed the line...

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN vUsers u ON u.ID = r.UpdateBy
```

Now I get the error:

```
 This field name is not known.
```

**Final EDIT**

Doing more testing, I removed all database connections and fields from the report.
The unknown field name still appeared.
So, I removed everything from the report - still had the error.
Copied the text fields to a brand new report and added the database and command.
The error is now gone and the report is working.
Very strange.

Comment: Did you grant roles or grant access to the other database?

Comment: Each database has the same login information. No roles.

Comment: did you try removing [Admin].[dbo]. and leave just Users?

Comment: I actually created a view in the main database to read the users table. Now I get This field name is not known.